# Laravel Collection only pushing one record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

When I try to push an array of records to my Laravel Collection, I end up with only the first record being inserted into the collection. It was working well before I made a few changes (related to $limit and $test) but now produces this bug.

```
public static function processOldOrders(int $limit = 1, bool $test = true)
    {
        //Read CSV and turn into a collection
        $allOldOrders = Excel::toArray([], 'orders.csv');

        $orderCollection = collect();

        $count = 0;

        foreach ($allOldOrders as $key => $oldOrder) {
            $orderCollection->push(
                (object) [
                    'order_id'        => ltrim($oldOrder[$key][0], "#"),
                    'order_created'   => $oldOrder[$key][4],
                    'email'           => $test ? 'test@test.com' : trim(strtolower($oldOrder[$key][5])),
                    'phone'           => ltrim($oldOrder[$key][12], "'"),
                    'first_name'      => $oldOrder[$key][7],
                    'last_name'       => $oldOrder[$key][8],
                    'purchase_status' => 'a_purchase',
                    'total_price'     => $oldOrder[$key][33],
                    'items'           => [],
                    'gift_cards'      => [],
                    'coupons'         => [],
                    'shipping_data'   => [],
                ]
            );
            $count++;
            if ($count >= $limit) {
                break;
            }
        }

        dd($orderCollection);
```

Comment: Make sure that you pass your $limit as more than 1, otherwise your loop will always break after the first record was pushed to the collection.

Comment: It is because your limit is 1 and count is 0. So when the loop will start it will work for 0 iteration means only one item will push, but for others the loop will break. For just an example make the limit to 2 and see how much it pushes.

Comment: in first iteration $count became equal to 1, and $count >= $limit -> true, so that's why it's break;

Comment: $limit is the default value. It is set with the command that fires this method in the controller, like this: php artisan customCommand --limit=10. This error persists even when value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

In your processOldOrders method by default you set limit = 1. And on the bottom,

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($allOldOrders as $key => $oldOrder) {
...
$count++;
if ($count >= $limit) {
      break;
}
...
```

there you check it with count. At first time `$count` is equal to 0, and you plus it 1. Then you checking it with `$limit`. By default limit is 1 . So it works only one time. Yu have to more than one limit where you call `processOldOrders` method

Comment: It should be a comment, and also you must have looked at this from above comments. Lolz

Comment: $limit is the default value. It is set with the command that fires this method in the controller, like this: php artisan  customCommand --limit=10. This error persists even when value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. But you forgot the output of `Excel::toArray()`, that it has sub-arrays.

```
array:1 [
  0 => array [    // <-- init
    0 => array [  // <-- CSV data
        ...
```

So, you can change your `$allOldOrders` to `$allOldOrders[0]` :

```
foreach ($allOldOrders[0] as $key => $oldOrder) {
    ...
}
```